# How to use jupyter on a server PC from a client PC

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, windows-server-2019

I am afraid this is a basic question, but I would like to know how to access the server PC from the client PC.

The client PC's OS is Windows 11 and the server PC's OS is Windows Server 2019. I usually connect to the server from the client PC using Remote Desktop Connection, an app that comes with Windows 11. Once I enter the server, I launch jupyter lab on the server (Fig. 1) and work with it.
[image]
However, I would like to use the jupyter lab on the server PC directly from the client PC's browser if possible. So, I input the server PC's IP address(x.xxx.xxx.xxx) and jupyter lab(8888/lab) into the client PC's browser (Fig.2), but it timed out and could not connect. When I make a remote desktop connection I input the account name and password, so I think that this is definitely missing something... Or do I need to authorize external access on the client PC's browser? Sorry for this amateur question, but I would appreciate any advice you can give me. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators/public-server.html#jupyter-public-server
This section of the documentation might answer your question

Comment: Dear Dmitri Chubarov, Thank you very much for your introduction to this very informative site. It looks like jupyter can be remotely controlled in this way. Thank you very much. Actually, I would like to control Neo4j from a client PC as well. If you know how to deal with this, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.